# jQuery plugin to merge two images and save the resulting one?

Tags: php, jquery, image, merge

I'm working on something that requires the following:

- There is an image with a particular header and footer, which is to serve as a kind of template/background
- Users need to be able to upload an image, crop it, and drag it onto the template, and ideally position it too
- New image gets saved

Do any of you happen to know a plugin or two that might achieve this functionality? I've got something working with jCrop, but I've done the image merging stuff myself, and it's not great. I'd prefer something more robust, so a standalone plugin would be best.

Thanks

Comment: Javascript can't write images. Any solution is going to have to invoke a backend service that takes the component pieces and combines them on the server-side.

Comment: Sorry should have made it clearer. I know that, the solution I'm using now uses PHP's GD library.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve something similar using HTML5 Canvases, but its not elegant and obviously wont work in every browser.

The idea is to simply draw those images to a canvas and then set an `img` object to the source of the canvas

> To save the canvas drawing as an image, we can set the source of an
>   image object to the image data URL. From there, a user can right click
>   on the image to save it to their local computer.  Alternatively, you
>   could also open up a new browser window with the image data url
>   directly and the user could save it from there.

```
// save canvas image as data url (png format by default)
var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();

// set canvasImg image src to dataURL
// so it can be saved as an image
document.getElementById("canvasImg").src = dataURL;
```

View the full tutorial [here](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/advanced/html5-canvas-save-drawing-as-an-image/)